# Enable Logoff Prompt

Tags: remote-desktop, prompt

As a new user to Remote Desktop, I mistakenly told the warning prompt about closing the session that I didn't want to be warned again.  Since I can't seem to remember to logoff the CORRECT way, I would like this warning window back.  How do I turn that prompt back on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `regedit.exe` and navigate to:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client

In there should be a DWord value named `ShowShutdownDialog`.

Set it to `1` (or delete the ShowShutdownDialog entry) if you want the RDP client to show the dialog, or `0` if you don't.

Comment: If regedit is disabled by your system administrator, ask them to do this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Techie.  I REALLY appreciate it.
I don't see the "Terminal Server Client" option listed from my side of things, so will forward your "How-To" to our I.T. department.
Again, Thank you! :)

Comment: They said I'm an admin' to this system, so would things be different on an XP machine vs. what you instructed me above?

Comment: Ahh, you should have mentioned XP in your question. ;)  I just tested on an XP machine here.  XP's RDP client's warning prompt doesn't give you the option to not ask again. It always asks...  no check box, so there no matching registry setting.  Since there's no check box, you didn't tell it to not show you again... soooo??  Does your IT department have any Group Policies in place that may be deciding that for you?

Comment: Hmm.....well I actually did receive that option (not pulling your leg), so that is strange indeed.  Does it make a difference that I am accessing this through a virtual machine?  I will check on the "Group Policies" issue.

Comment: "Does it make a difference that I am accessing this through a virtual machine" Depends, is the VM running XP?